# Kafka transaction message reading repeats when doing rebalance

Tags: apache-kafka, transactions, restart, consumer, producer

I have a consumer topic CTOPIC ( data is written by a an external agent) and a producer PTOPIC. The flow is consumer reads messages from CTOPIC , processes it and writes to the producer topic.
The code is as below

```
tranxId = "O8XXD";
cache = new HashMap()

RestartSource.onFailuresWithBackoff(minBackoff = 2.seconds, maxBackoff = 600.seconds, randomFactor = 0.4)
{ () =>
  
  Transactional.source(consumerProperties, Subscriptions.topics("CTOPIC"))

    .mapAsync(1)(myMessage => {

        upsertDLQ(myMessage) // insert/update myMessge into DLQ and with the  count of retries

        EvaluateMyMessage(myMessage)  //calls google API  via n/w call for e.g.
            .recoverWith{

                case exception:NetworkException =>{
                    //log  the error and do a backoff-retry via the above RestartSource block
                    
                    if (DLQ_retry_count(myMessage)> 4{
                        Future(ProducerMessage.passThrough[String, String, PartitionOffset](myMessage.partitionOffset))
                        }
                    else {
                        Future failed exception

                    }
                }
            }
    })
    .via(Transactional.flow(producerProperties, tranxId))  //write to  "PTOPIC"
}.runWith(Sink.foreach(res => log.info(s" Response:" +s" ${res.passThrough}")))



[info] a.k.i.TransactionalSourceLogic - [0cd3d] Starting. StageActor                                     
Actor[akka://application/system/Materializers/StreamSupervisor-0/$$b#987621478]
```

'''
ConsumerConfig values:

```
auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
auto.offset.reset = latest
bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092]
connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
enable.auto.commit = false
fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
group.id = mygroup-1
group.instance.id = null
heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
isolation.level = read_committed
max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
max.poll.records = 500
reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
request.timeout.ms = 30000
retry.backoff.ms = 100
```

'''
ProducerConfig values:

```
acks = 1
batch.size = 16384
bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092]
buffer.memory = 33554432
client.dns.lookup = default
connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
delivery.timeout.ms = 120000
enable.idempotence = true
max.block.ms = 60000
max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 1
max.request.size = 1048576
metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
partitioner.class = class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner
receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
request.timeout.ms = 30000
retries = 2147483647
retry.backoff.ms = 100
sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
transaction.timeout.ms = 60000
transactional.id = O8XXD
```

Messges  M1,  M2, M3, M4 come in sequence  and at the time when the 2nd message M2  arrives there  is a network error , a rebalace would accur.

My  expecation is M2 should be retried for 4 times but I see M3 , M4 also coming in immediatly and its like M2, M3, M4 all trying to get processed. And this goes on for about 3-4 minutes
And after this period it gets commited (and  M2,M3 and M4 are in dLq as expected).

But how can I stop  reading M3, M4 when M2 has still not been committed ? Because of the rebalance M2 is read by the code by about 7-8 times. Please help

Comment: Consumer has enable.auto.commit = false but I don't see anything in the example which commits the offsets. If that is true, this could cause the message to be reconsumed if a rebalance occurs.

Comment: Commits are done by Transactional.flow(producerProperties, tranxId)  so thats why its set as false. This block will commit the messages and auto commit is not required.. Refer: https://doc.akka.io/docs/alpakka-kafka/current/transactions.html#recovery-from-failure